# Detect Word Then Send Embed Message (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code that i am stuck on and I don't know how to fix it!! Can someone please help me:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, member: discord.Member, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    member = ctx.member if not member else member
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild

    if "done" in message.content:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
            title="Nickname:",
        )

        embed.add_field(name="User Nickname:",
                        value=str(member.nick), inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Bot coded by Grenadevisuals on instagram!",
                         icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)

        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions, for starters `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.` and `copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.` apply here.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code help you:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "done" in message.content:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
            title="Nickname:",
        )

        embed.add_field(name="User Nickname:",
                        value=str(message.author.nick), inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Bot coded by Grenadevisuals on instagram!",
                         icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.guild.icon_url)

        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

P.S. If you want more arguments, you can add these arguments in function after `message` argument, example: `message, member: discord.Member, guild: discord.Guild = None`